# Adjusting Collection View Cells for Screen Size

Tags: ios, xcode

This is the code I am using to setup my collection view.

```
- (void) setUpCollectionView {

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];

[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];

[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320, 566)];

[self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

}
```

I am setting the item size of the flow layout to a set size. I want to know I can adjust this size for the current screen size the user is using. Thanks.

Comment: What size is your collection view? How are you setting that? I'm guessing that you want your cell to be the same size as your collection view since you're using paging.

Comment: The problem is my collection view is stretching to fit screen sizes but my cells are not. The collection view automatically resizes itself in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection view is set up with constraints to make it adjust to the screen size, then set your cells size to be the same as the collection view.

```
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height)];
```